# Setting up default azure web application with AD auth through Visual Studio returns error

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I wanted to create a simple application that uses Azure AD for authentication.

I decided to do this through Visual Studio, so I:

1. Created a new MVC project with Work or School Account auth enabled. This creates the sample application and sets upp an app registration in my tenant.
2. Publish the application to Azure. This creates the web application and hosts it in azure with a .azurewebsites.net domain.
3. Adjust the reply URLs of the app registration in AD tenant to fit my app.

For clarity here is my web.config (generated):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-xxx-20180626122432.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-xxx-20180626122432;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="e9xx-xxx-xxxf-9xxd-xxx" />
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
    <add key="ida:ClientSecret" value="xxxA=" />
    <add key="ida:Domain" value="xxx.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="ida:TenantId" value="xxx-fxxa-xxe7-9xxx-xxx" />
    <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://xxx.azurewebsites.net" />
  </appSettings>
```

Why is it even generating a connectionstring? I don't want a database, this is also what seems to cause the error I get.

That should be it as far as I know. But when I log in to my site I get the following error:

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file
>   specified]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to
>   locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server
>   Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime
>   feature is enabled.)]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling) +821
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +332
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +699
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +89
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +426
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) +191
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +90
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +209    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__36(DbConnection
>   t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c) +10
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget
>   target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection
>   connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +360
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32()
>   +426    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() +10
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1
>   operation) +189
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action
>   operation) +78
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +175
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +552
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1
>   commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String
>   createDatabaseScript) +90
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection
>   connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection
>   storeItemCollection) +171
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection
>   connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection
>   storeItemCollection) +76
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() +134
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection
>   connection) +119
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +142
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
>   targetMigration) +78
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext
>   internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
>   +89    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext
>   objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +116
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState
>   existenceState) +218
>
>   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext
>   context) +151
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
>   +76    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action
>   action) +60
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
>   +357    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext
>   c) +7
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
>   +110    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1
>   action) +198
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
>   +73    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +30    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) +16
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>   +15    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>   +38    System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +83
>   AdAuthPocDamco.Models.ADALTokenCache..ctor(String signedInUserId) in
>   c:\users\manielse\source\repos\AdAuthPocDamco\AdAuthPocDamco\Models\AdalTokenCache.cs:26
>   AdAuthPocDamco.Startup.b__7_0(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification
>   context) in
>   c:\users\manielse\source\repos\AdAuthPocDamco\AdAuthPocDamco\App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs:54
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.d__1a.MoveNext()
>   +4952    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +26
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.d__1a.MoveNext()
>   +6433    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +61
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext()
>   +571    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +61
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext() +255
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +61
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__5.MoveNext()
>   +182    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +61
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext() +638
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +61
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__5.MoveNext()
>   +182    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +61
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__2.MoveNext()
>   +180    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +69
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +64
>   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +380    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it even generating a connectionstring?

I can't reproduce the issue that you mentioned. In my web.config file, there is no database connection string created. And It works correctly on my side.

> I don't want a database, this is also what seems to cause the error I get.

Yes, you are right. Since the Azure WebApp can't connect to the local database by default.

If you don't want a database, you could remove the SQL connection during publish to Azure WebApp. Or you could create another Web project and try it again.